# Infragistics charts, how to draw LineSeries with separate Y-Axis and common X-Axis?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, infragistics

could you help me with this ?

I need to draw 2 or more LineSeries in the same chart, but each line must have its own Y-Axis and all lines must share the same X-Axis.

I need something like this :

[image]

Here is my Xaml code which displays 3 lineseries but with the same Y-Axis :

```
    <ig:XamDataChart>

        <ig:XamDataChart.Axes>

            <ig:CategoryXAxis  x:Name="catXAxis" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"  Label="{}{Label}"/>

            <ig:NumericYAxis x:Name="numYAxis" >
                <ig:NumericYAxis.LabelSettings>
                    <ig:AxisLabelSettings Location="OutsideLeft"/>
                </ig:NumericYAxis.LabelSettings>
            </ig:NumericYAxis>

        </ig:XamDataChart.Axes>

        <ig:XamDataChart.Series>

            <ig:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" ValueMemberPath="X" XAxis="{Binding ElementName=catXAxis}"
                YAxis="{Binding ElementName=numYAxis}"/>

            <ig:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" ValueMemberPath="Y" XAxis="{Binding ElementName=catXAxis}"
                YAxis="{Binding ElementName=numYAxis}"/>

            <ig:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" ValueMemberPath="Z" XAxis="{Binding ElementName=catXAxis}"
                YAxis="{Binding ElementName=numYAxis}"/>

        </ig:XamDataChart.Series>

    </ig:XamDataChart>
```

I tried to add 2 more NumericYAxes, but without success.

Thank you for your help.

Alex.

Comment: The required screen would need 2 separate instances of `XamDataChart` with same `CategoryXAxis` binding. Have you tried that already?

Comment: No I haven't, I'll try that, thank you